# 1048, "Column 'execution_period' cannot be null"

Tags: python, mysql

Main idea of these work is to parse each page from pagination(it has 152 pages), and put these data to db.  while running error occurred, column 'execution_period' cannot be null". 
in my DataFrame I did this:

```
df['Срок исполнения'] = df['Срок исполнения'].fillna(0)
df['Дата принятия решения/дела'] = df['Дата принятия решения/дела'].fillna(0)
```

don't know how to fix it.

```
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df_list = pd.read_html('sanction.xls')
    df = df_list[0]
     database = MySQLdb.connect (host="host", user = "root", passwd = "password", db = "db", charset='utf8')

    mycursor = database.cursor()
    cursor = database.cursor()
    query = """INSERT INTO sanction (
                id,
                organization_type, organization, date,
                decision_number, penalty_type, penalty_way,
                penalty, violation, execution_period,
                article, note, type_npa,
                department, uploaded_date)
                VALUES (
                null,
                   %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s,"%%d.%%m.%%Y"),
                %s, %s, %s,
                %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s,"%%d.%%m.%%Y"),
                %s, %s, %s,
                %s, %s)"""


    for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
        organization_type = sheet.cell(r,1).value
        organization = sheet.cell(r,2).value
        date = (sheet.cell(r,3).value)
        decision_number = sheet.cell(r,4).value
        penalty_type = sheet.cell(r,5).value
        penalty_way = sheet.cell(r,6).value
        penalty = sheet.cell(r,7).value
        violation = sheet.cell(r,8).value
        execution_period = sheet.cell(r,9).value
        article =sheet.cell(r,10).value
        note =sheet.cell(r,11).value
        type_npa =sheet.cell(r,12).value
        department =sheet.cell(r,13).value
        uploaded_date =datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") 


        values = (organization_type, organization, date, decision_number, penalty_type, 
                      penalty_way,penalty, violation, execution_period,article, note, type_npa, department,uploaded_date)


        mycursor.execute(query, values)
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of your "sanction" table? Sounds like you are trying to insert a null value into a non-nullable column.

Comment: @user7733611 my sanction table is the same like here: https://nationalbank.kz/index.cfm?docid=3227&switch=russian&organization=&organizationid=&organizationtypeid=&typeid=&kindid=&startdate=&enddate=&npatypeid=&sourceid=&view=list&start=601

Comment: You need to check your inputs, [If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: @Uueerdo what if I change in my db column by default null, will it cause any troubles?

Comment: That depends on how you are using the data. If a null ("no date") value should allowed, then the column should not be defined as NOT NULL.